# UI/UX interface book

Tags: books

Can any one suggest me some books for basic userinterface and userexperience with simple english and good examples

Comment: Do you want User Interface design or User Experience in general. The two can be quite different.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of user experience books worth reading here are a few:

Don't Make me Think  (revisited version out soon)
About Face 3
The Inmates Are Running the Asylum 
Information Architecture for the World Wide Web

A few more on my page at:

http://uxstew.tumblr.com/post/59117592166/recommended-ux-books